# Detecting if the system is idling

Tags: java

The following code detects if the system is idling. It approaches the problem by using the `Robot` class to take a screenshot, waits for a while, and then takes another screenshot. It then compares screenshot 1 with screenshot 2. If  a certain amount of change is detected, it presumes the system is idling, else the system is active.

Please suggest code changes or even a different solution!

```
package base;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class CheckIdle extends Thread {
    private Robot robot;
    private double threshHold = 0.05;
    private int activeTime;
    private int idleTime;
    private boolean idle;
    private Rectangle screenDimenstions;

    public CheckIdle(int activeTime, int idleTime) {
        this.activeTime = activeTime;
        this.idleTime = idleTime;

        // Get the screen dimensions
        // MultiMonitor support.
        int screenWidth = 0;
        int screenHeight = 0;

        GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnv = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] graphicsDevices = graphicsEnv.getScreenDevices();

        for (GraphicsDevice screens : graphicsDevices) {
            DisplayMode mode = screens.getDisplayMode();
            screenWidth += mode.getWidth();

            if (mode.getHeight() > screenHeight) {
                screenHeight = mode.getHeight();
            }
        }

        screenDimenstions = new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        // setup the robot.
        robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        idle = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            BufferedImage screenShot = robot
                    .createScreenCapture(screenDimenstions);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(idle ? idleTime : activeTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedImage screenShot2 = robot
                    .createScreenCapture(screenDimenstions);

            if (compareScreens(screenShot, screenShot2) < threshHold) {
                idle = true;
            } else {
                idle = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private double compareScreens(BufferedImage screen1, BufferedImage screen2) {
        int counter = 0;
        boolean changed = false;

        // Count the amount of change.
        for (int i = 0; i < screen1.getWidth() && !changed; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < screen1.getHeight(); j++) {
                if (screen1.getRGB(i, j) != screen2.getRGB(i, j)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        return (double) counter
                / (double) (screen1.getHeight() * screen1.getWidth()) * 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckIdle idleChecker = new CheckIdle(20000, 1000);
        idleChecker.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: If, for instance, a Flash animation is being played in foreground, it wouldn't be detected as idling.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Monitoring input (mouse/keyboard) will bypass that problem, but to my knowledge it will require 3d party libraries to capture the global inputs? Any other suggestion to avoid that problem?

Comment: The solution is very system-dependant. For instance, in Windows you have to hook into mouse/keyboard events using JNI and the system API. Why are you avoiding 3rd party libraries? If there are any that solve your problem, why would you complicate yourself?

Comment: In this case I am trying to find a Java only solution. It seems that I will require both a Linux and Windows 3rd party library to solve this problem. At first glace that seems more complicated, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Superficially: use `final` for `threshold`. Do not do `if (a < b) return true else false` but do `return (a < b);` or `return (a >= b);` - whichever you need. `boolean changed` needs to go. Use fractions, not percents - get rid of `* 100`. Rename counter to something like `pixelDifferenceCount`. Also, first half of `CheckIdle` should be its own method.

Comment: One problem with this approach is the clock. If there is an analogue clock with a second hand on screen then the program will never detect an idle state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
        if (compareScreens(screenShot, screenShot2) < threshHold) {
            idle = true;
        } else {
            idle = false;
        }
```

Isn't this better as

```
        idle = compareScreens(screenShot, screenShot2) < threshHold;
```

Here, why initialize robot to null first? Isn't this given in the constructor? And why do you continue if there is an AWT exception? Doesn't it mean no GUI? perhaps your constructor should throw that exception. Otherwise, perhaps it is better to have a larger block for try catch. The reason is that the exception handling code is better away from the main sequence. You use robot in the run code. So in order for that to run, robot has to be non null. So catching the exception here is not correct.

```
    // setup the robot.
    robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You also set idle to false, which is not really needed because it is initialized to false by java.

Why do you take an extra screen shot? Isn't this what you mean?

```
public void run() {
 try {
    BufferedImage screenShot = null;
    BufferedImage screenShotPrev 
         = robot.createScreenCapture(screenDimenstions);
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(idle ? idleTime : activeTime);
        screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(screenDimenstions);
        idle = compareScreens(screenShotPrev, screenShot) < threshHold;
        screenShotPrev = screenShot;
    }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
 }
```

Here, where do you use the changed? (as noted in comment to the question.)

```
private double compareScreens(BufferedImage screen1, BufferedImage screen2) {
    int counter = 0;
    boolean changed = false;

    // Count the amount of change.
    for (int i = 0; i < screen1.getWidth() && !changed; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < screen1.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (screen1.getRGB(i, j) != screen2.getRGB(i, j)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return (double) counter
            / (double) (screen1.getHeight() * screen1.getWidth()) * 100;
}
```

The for loop may be better as

```
 int[] s1 = ((DataBufferInt) screen1.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();  
 int[] s2 = ((DataBufferInt) screen2.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();  
 for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
     if (s1[i] != s2[i]) counter++;
```

Since it avoids multiple calls to getRGB.

And is there any chance of getHeight or getWidth returning 0?
Also, I assume that you are calling .run instead of .start only because you are testing?

Comment: Hi, thank you very mush for the feedback. I agree with comments, and will make the changes likewise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to globally detect the current mouse location:

```
// prevent HeadlessException
if (GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()) {
    System.err.println("headless graphics environment detected");
    return;
}
PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point point = info.getLocation();
```

However, you would still need to use a third party library such as [JIntellitype](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) to detect keyboard activity.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this! I will change the implementation around this.